# Badge not showing styled

Tags: java, vaadin, badge

I want to add `badges` to a `grid`.

what I did is follow [this](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/badge). I added the `.json` file in:

```
frontend/themes/common-themes/theme.json
```

this is the `.json`

```
{
  "lumoImports": ["badge"]
}
```

and this is the code that I use to add it to the `grid` (current all my items have 2 `labels`, respectively `L1` and `L2`

```
grid.addComponentColumn(t -> {
            var layout = new HorizontalLayout();

            for (var label : t.getLabels()) {
                var tmp = new Span(new Span(label.getName()));
                tmp.getElement().getThemeList().add("badge");
                layout.add(tmp);
            }
            return layout;
        });
```

my project runs with no errors, but this is the result:

[image]

how do I make them come out as in the documentation? I feel like I missed a crucial step

---

When I try to add `@Theme("commom-theme")` to my my class:

```
@PageTitle("Technology")
@Route(value = "")
@Theme("commom-theme")
public class TechnologyLayout extends VerticalLayout {

....

}
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
... 11 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're *only* including the badge module for Lumo, not the colors etc. (That instruction you linked to is not very clear on the matter, but that's what the `<...>,` refers to.)

Try this instead:

```
{
  "lumoImports" : [ "typography", "color", "spacing", "badge", "utility" ]
}
```

---

When I try to add `@Theme("commom-layout")` to my my class:

```
@PageTitle("Technology")
@Route(value = "")
@Theme("commom-layout")
public class TechnologyLayout extends VerticalLayout {

....

}
```

I get this error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
... 11 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I added them and still the same output. Do I have to link the `.json` to the file I am creating the `Badge` in (with some `annotation`)?

Comment: No, the only things that you need to do is have a theme.json with that content, and load the theme with @Theme("common-themes"). Actually, are you doing that last part?

Comment: I did try to add it but I get an `IllegalStateException`. I'll add it to the question